# Porting C++ Builder project to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, export, c++builder

I have a project made with C++ Builder 10.2 (Tokyo). I would like to ask how can I export it to Visual Studio - in Visual C++/Winforms(preferrable) or C#, so it can be compiled there again and work as in C++ Builder.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: C# would be a complete rewrite, and if you used the VCL in C++Builder, even C++ with WinForms would be quite a rewrite. It is not just a simple port.

Comment: If the project wasn't written to use portable coding, then it won't port easily, if at all.